# How to calculate the length of the image of the curve $\Gamma$?

Tags: mathematical-physics, complex-integration

How to calculate the length of the image of the curve $\Gamma= \{z(t) :z (t) =at, t \in [0,1]\}$ under the mapping $w = z^n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}, a \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: In what context has this question arisen? Did you search "calculate curve length" anywhere? What did you find? What part of it didn't you understand?

Comment: Did you take calculus classes where they discuss the formula for the length of curves?